# regex pattern match in java

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse string between  and  in ws service SOAP response. I have used below pattern to match the strings
Pattern:-

```
<ns2:resut>(.*)<\\/ns2:resut>
```

For the string 1 it works fine but in some of the response like in string 2 response is empty.

String 1:-

```
<soapenv:Body><ns2:updateCustomerResponse><ns2:resut>ATM: T, EMAIL: T, FAX: T, INTERNET SUBE: T, ISKULTURSANAT: T, ISTEYATIRIM: T, IVR: T, KUMBARAFON: T, POSTA IS: T, MAXIMUM: T, MOBIL KANALLAR SOSYAL MEDYA: T, SMS: T, TEL GSM: T, TEL EV: T, TEL IS: T</ns2:resut></ns2:updateCustomerResponse></soapenv:Body>
```

String 2:-

```
<soapenv:Body><ns2:updateCustomerResponse><ns2:resut/></ns2:updateCustomerResponse></soapenv:Body>
```

How can i achieve to match both the strings with single pattern. Expected result for string 2 is null or blank.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: The first question is what is this (highlighted) <ns2:resut>(.*)<`\\ `/ns2:resut> ?

Comment: SOAP is XML.  Is there some reason you don't want to use an XML parser?

Comment: I have millions of request/response in my hand and with java 8 new lambda expression i found it much faster than xml parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.Tested in [Regexe](http://www.regexe.com/)

```
<ns2:resut((>(.*)</ns2:resut>)|/>)
```

Also read how to write [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) with conditions.Sample [Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: I got my expected result in group3. I will also go through this tutorial.
Thanks !!